# Compute division of two computed columns from 2 tables derived from a single table

Tags: sql

I have created one table as below:

```
select trim(panno) as pan, sum(deposit_amoumt) as total_amount
from tbl_abc 
where remarks in ('A', 'B', 'C')
and date < '2018-02-01'
group by 1
```

And another table as below:

```
select trim(panno) as pan_no, sum(deposit_amoumt) as dep_amt
from tbl_abc 
where remarks in ('R', 'S')
and date < '2018-02-01'
group by 1
```

The 2 tables are different with respect to remarks.
Now I want to find the ratio of the 2 deposit amounts for all the pans.

How do I go about it?
Can it be done only with joins or can be done without join as well?

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: Will keep a note of this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select trim(panno) as pan,
       sum(case when remarks in ('A', 'B', 'C') then deposit_amount end) as total_amount,
       sum(case when remarks in ('R', 'S') then deposit_amount end) as rep_amount
from tbl_abc 
where date < '2018-02-01'
group by 1;
```

The ratio is just the ratio of the two expressions.

Comment: I ran the above code and created a temp table in order to divide the 2 ratios as many rows had denominator zero and while dividing on the fly gave me error of cannot divide by zero.
Thanks for the help.